Wordpress Multisite - 2 wp_Users Tables?
I have a Wordpress Multiste with 2 Sites. Each Site has a Site ID logically.
I see for Site A a wp_a_options and a wp_a_users Table but I do not see any wp_b_users table for Site b (I see a wp_b_options table) ?? This seems to be not oky, am I right!?
I am expecting to see two WP Users Table in a Multisite Configuration for a 2 Site Configuration.

WordPress Multisite does not use two different wp_users tables. In a WordPress Multisite network, all the sites within the network share the same wp_users and wp_usermeta tables across the entire network. This means that user accounts are stored globally, and the same wp_users table is used for all sites in the network. One user can be an admin in site 1 and a customer in site 2 which is through wp_1_capabilities wp_2_capabilities

In a WordPress Multisite configuration, user management works a bit differently than in single-site installations. In a Multisite setup, there is only one wp_users table for the entire network, regardless of the number of sites. This table stores all users across all sites in the network.
For each individual site, there are entries in the wp_sitemeta and wp_site tables to manage which users have access to which sites, but the actual user data is not duplicated in separate wp_b_users or similar tables. Instead, the relationships between users and sites are maintained in the wp_sitemeta table and the wp_site table.
So, in your case, having just a single wp_users table along with separate wp_a_options and wp_b_options tables is completely normal and expected behavior in a WordPress Multisite setup.
If you have users that are part of Site B, their information will still reside in the wp_users table, and their relationships with Site B will be managed through the multisite system.

thank you for this info
